Can camera recording apps access camera function of Iphone while the phone is locked? (but not black screen / sleep mode)
I understand that the black screen limits recording through the iphone's camera. Understandably so. But can apps utilize the camera while the phone is awake yet still locked? I know that the default app lets you access the camera while it is still locked but can other apps do it? Do they have access to functions such as video recording and geo location while screen is awake (yet locked)?
Now I understand an app may need to be active for it to have access to camera. Can an app be made active while the screen is locked? using a side button shortcut?
Please let me know, thank you.
Have not tested it out myself yet and seeking answers from someone with experience

I'm going to say: no.
If you take an app, and put logging into all the major functions in AppDelegate.swift, you will notice that if you hit the lock button, your app will log:
MAIN: applicationWillResignActive(_:)

(use something like:)
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print ("MAIN: \(#function)" )
}

Once you are in the background, generally speaking, you can't record:
How to record video when application is in background ios
